# Como hago para validar la información ingresada en mi formulario a través de mi ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Este es mi codigo para abrir el modal

```
**<div class="fondosainventario">
    <div class="container submenutercer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="modal" href="#agregarclasificacion" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarclasificacion">
                    <span>
                    <img src='{% static "img/nuevaclasificacion.png" %}' alt="" class="img-responsive" title="">
                    </span>
                    <p>Nueva Clasificación</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> </div>**
```

Este es mi modal:

```
**<div class="modal fade" id="agregarclasificacion" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Nueva clasificación</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="formatolinea" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label>Clasificador</label>
                        <select id="clasificador" name="clasificador">
                            <option>Nombre del clasificador</option>
                            {% for obj in clasificador %}
                            <option>{{obj.nombre}} {{obj.apellidos}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        <label>Hacienda</label>
                        <select id="hacienda" name="hacienda" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
                            <option>Seleccione la hacienda</option>
                            <option value="San Gregorio">San Gregorio</option>
                            <option value="Potreritos">Potreritos</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Variedad</label>
                        <select name="variedad" required="">
                            <option>Seleccione la variedad</option>
                            <optgroup label="Variedad" id="variedads" style='display: none;'>
                                <option value="Freedom">freedom</option>
                                <option value="Vendela">vendela</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="Variedad" id="variedadp" style='display: none;'>
                                <option>Freedom</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        <label>Cantidad Tabacos</label>
                        <input type="number" name="cant_tabacos" title="" required="" placeholder="Cantidad de tabacos">
                        <label>Unidad por Tabaco</label>
                        <select name="unid_tabaco" onChange="otro(this.value);">
                            <option>Unidades por tabaco</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>25</option>
                            <option value="Otro" id="otro">Otro</option>
                        </select>
                        <label id="digite" style=' display: none; '>Digite la cantidad</label>
                        <input type="number" name="tabaco" id="unidad" style=' display: none; ' onChange="cambiar(this.value);">
                        <button class="guardar" type="submit" id="validar"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                        <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.containerfluid -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modalbody -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
            <!-- /.modalfooter -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->**
```

Y lo que quiero es que si no ingreso toda la información me mueste un mensaje que diga le falta tal cosa, y si la información es correcta me muestre un mensaje que diga la infomacion ha sido almacenada.

```
Pero no se como hacerlo, lo quiero hacer con javascript
```

Comment: Hola @Angie, ¿por casualidad intentaste una búsqueda para ver si encontrabas cómo se podía hacer? Y si es así, ¿hay algo en particular que te haya traido problemas?

Comment: Hola la verdad es que no he encontrado mucha información, encontré algo con formularios pero a la hora de ejecutarlo no me valida nada.

Comment: Ya probaste [jQueryValidate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)? revisalo, seguro ahi encuentras tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola, utiliza parsley. hay mucha documentación y ejemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con parsley, aca te dejo un link con un ejemplo, que a mi modo de ver, se ajusta a lo que tu necesitas:

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Un saludo, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola @chenio. ¿No te parecería mejor incluir información de ese ejemplo dentro de tu respuesta, de modo de que sea una respuesta más completa? Incluso si en algún momento ese enlace llegara a no estar disponible, seguiría siendo una respuesta válida.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion a tu problema es jQuery.Validate.js, un plugin de jQuery el cual te permite verificar tu formulario antes de enviar la informacion, tiene distintas funcionalidades ya sea validar el formato de un campo para un email, que el texto de un campo sea igual a otro, etc. Te dejo un ejemplo sobre funcionalidades sencillas y es mas o menos lo que andas buscando:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newAccount').validate({
        rules: {
            userName: { required: true },
            pass: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            passConfir: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#pass"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            userName: {
                required: "Please write a user name...",
            },
            pass: {
                required: "Please write a password...",
                minlength: "Password must have at least 5 characters...",
            },
            passConfir: {
                required: "Please write a password...",
                minlength: "Password must have at least 5 characters...",
                equalTo: "Password must match...",
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please write an email...",
                email: "Format must be: example@domain.com",
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            register();
        }
    });
});


function register() {
    alert("Account created!!");
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Register!</button>

<form id="newAccount">
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create your account!!!!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label text-info">Username:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label text-info">Password:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="******" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label text-info">Confirm Password:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="password" id="passConfir" name="passConfir" placeholder="******" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label text-info">Email:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="create" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Create account" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

Y por supuesto te dejo [el link de jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Espero te sirva.